# How can I simulate a request from a custom IP address in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, network-programming

I want to send multiple requests to my localhost:3000 server from various clients, and I want to simulate that scenario. I'm using the clj-http library to make a request:

```
(client/get "http://localhost:3000/")
```

How do I make the request from an ip address other than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: You can use all the addresses in the `127.0.0.0/8` block. The entire block has loopback addresses, although most people just use `127.0.0.1`. You can use any or all of them to test from one to the other. By the way, IPv6 has only one loopback address: `::1`.

Comment: Do you need to use actual network traffic? A Ring handler is just a function from request to response, and it's easy to call that function with a request that claims to be from any address you like.

Comment: what's your purpose of this, will your server program behaves differently?

Comment: there's supposed to be a kubernetes ingress load balancer that routes the request to one of the replicas based on the client id in the header of the request

Answer (score 0):

One simple answer is to fire up a linux VM in VirtualBox (either directly or by using Vagrant), then make the request from the VM.

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/index) is an easy-to-use driver since the config files (i.e. `Vagrantfile`) is simple text and can be checked into git.  You can control the IP address of the VM with a simple entry like

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

See both the

- [the general Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/index)
- and [the Getting Start docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vagrant)

(note that they are in 2 different locations!)

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to have a simple client as a Docker image (or combination of base image and a custom command) and you can launch them fairly quickly. See this answer for some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/483566

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you testing? If it's a unit test, send a request to the handler with the desired IP address in the data structure.

If it's an integration test, spin up a server, and use the java library org.apache.http to hit the end points.

To spin up the server use the `once` fixture. It looks similar to this

```
(use-fixtures :once
              (fn [tests]
                (before stuff) ;start server here
                (tests)
                (after stuff))) ;shut down server here
```

This is the [org.apache.http documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.1.x/). [This is the subpage you'll want to look at.](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.1.x/current/httpcore5-h2/apidocs/) Read about setting the Requests. You'll want to set the IP address in the header of a request and then send it. [Baeldung shows examples of using org.apache.http in java.](https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-a-rest-api) which you can translate into Clojure code